# Sending pdf (ebook) file after the user successfully subscribe to the website using sendgrid

Tags: wordpress, sendgrid, subscription, subscribe

i am integrating the sendgrid to my wordpress site. the subscription part is done through the plugin of sendgrid and now i want to sent the pdf(ebook) file once the user has successfully verified by the email. once the email of the user is verified a email containing the pdf file should be sent automatically to the verified user.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i can see you have to use sendgrid `webhooks` and `Api` in order to send Autoresponders for your clients.

you can read [Autoresponders](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Glossary/autoresponder.html) to find out what they are.
and also read [Setting Up the Inbound Parse Webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/Inbound_Parse_Webhook/setting_up_the_inbound_parse_webhook.html) to use webhooks.
sendgrid provide different libraries for you to make development process easier. read [Web API v3](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/index.html) for more info on this.

if you don't have enough skills in programming i prefer you to use `mailerlite` it provides real easy automation + documentation and also free plan.

you can read about `mailerlite` automation [here](https://www.mailerlite.com/automation)

Comment: sorry i am a newbie to the sendgrid and i don't have that much command in the backend. i read the automation part but didn't find the automation part. is there anything example or have you done on some projects ??

Comment: @AayamAashish read the answer again i hope it solve your problem